# SharePoint 2010 Search Issues - Scope not working!

Tags: search, search-results, search-scope, people-search, enterprise-search

I'm having some issues with Search and Search Scopes. Basically I have created a Search Center site and linked it to my site collection in Site Settings->Search Settings. But it doesn't seem to be working properly.

Basically my site structure is like this:
    Home
    Site A
      Site A.1
      Site A.2
    Site B
      Site B.1
      Site B.2
    Site C
      Site C.1
      Site C.2

Now within all sites A.1, A.2, B.1, B.2... there are documents and files. Now when I search, I choose "All Sites" from the drop down and enter a document name, but I get no results found...**UNLESS** I am within the same site as the document itself.

So for example if I am on the Home site and I search for a document (document is stored in site C.1), I get no results...however, if I am on the Site C or C.1 or C.2 and I search for the document I will get it as a result. Is this the correct behaviour?

How can I get around this so I can search  for documents from any site and get all results?

Is the solution to this to create a new scope rather than use the All Sites scope?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, I used this guide, basically I deleted my Search Center and started again, Search and People Search works pretty smoothly now.

http://www.sharepointsharon.com/2010/11/search-set-up/

Comment: The link you provided is dead now.